# Adding non-osgi jars to RCP4 project

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, rcp

I have the following situation.  I rely on a 3rd party jar called foo.jar.  That jar has many non-osgi dependencies.  I created a new project "Plug-in from existing JAR archives", selected all of foo.jars non-osgi dependencies and exported it as a "deployable plugin and fragment" called foo.libs.jar.

My RCP4 project is a a feature-based product. In my main RCP project I go to the target file, navigate to the Content tab and checkmark foo.jar and foo.libs.jar.  I then go to my project file and select "validate" and receive the message "No problems were detected".

Any clue what I'm doing wrong or need to be doing to get this to work? Do I have to explicitly set foo.libs.jar as a dependency of foo.jar?  I've tried to do that in my main projects manifest->dependency tab and the runConfigurations->Plug-ins, and added foo.libs.jar to the feature.xmls->Included plug-ins tab but it didn't seem to work.

Thanks!

===UPDATE===

I think my issue may fall into the case of bundle fragments and embedded dependencies.  As an example:

```
- I create foo.libs.jar. One of the jars inside it is activemq.jar 
  I need access to javax.jms.ExceptionListener
- The manifest for foo.libs.jar contains activemq.jar in the 
  Bundle-ClassPath, and javax.jms in the Export-Package sections
- foo.jar contains foo.libs.jar in its Class-Path. It contains  
  javax.jms in its Import-Package and Export-Package sections
- I created a "Plug-in from existing JAR archives" project which has
  foo.jar and foo.libs.jar in it.
- The manifest for the project has foo.jar and foo.libs.jar in the 
  Bundle-Classpath section. The Import-Package section contains 
  javax.jms
- If I export this bundle to my project, and run validate I get 
  errors saying javax.jms cannot be found.
- If I omit the javax.jms from the bundles Import-Package there
  are no validation errors but I will get a ClassNotFoundException
```

I kinda feel like this may be an issue with embedded jars and Bundle-ClassPaths...

My bundle has

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: my.name
Bundle-SymbolicName: my.name
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-ClassPath: foo.jar
Export-Package: list_of_my_packages
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

And foo.jar has

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1489769501680
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: foo
Bundle-SymbolicName: foo
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Class-Path: foo.libs.jar
Created-By: 1.8.0_71 (Oracle Corporation)
Export-Package: javax.jms  (and other stuff, omitted)
Import-Package: javax.jms;resolution:=optional (and other stuff, omitted)
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"
Tool: Bnd-2.4.0.201411031536
```

And foo.libs.jar has

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Foo libs
Bundle-SymbolicName: foo.libs
Bundle-Version: 1.1.0
Bundle-ClassPath: activemq-all.jar, (and others which I ommitted)
Export-Package: javax.jms, (and others which I ommitted)
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question lacks details, but the issue with "no class found" is quite typical for OSGI.

Check the MANIFEST.MF of both of your bundles. foo.libs.jar must have a declaration of a package for your "missing" class in 'Export-Package' directive, while foo.jar must have same package in 'Import-Package'. Since you managed to reach to the point when you get an exception, it seems like you missing package declaration for some.class.in.a.jar.in.foo.libs.jar in 'Import-Package' of foo.jar.

Main rule is following: a bundle may access only the classes within itself + the ones, imported via manifest. There are exceptions like bundle fragments and embedded dependencies, but I believe we can omit them for this case.

Generally, problem is solved when you properly set both 'Import-' and 'Export-Package' directives in manifests of your bundles. If you need more detailed help, please provide more details about how you make foo.jar and foo.lib.jar (by hands, by maven plugin, by gradle, which settings you use etc.)

Comment: Thanks for helping out with this. I made some changes to how I package everything and have listed the steps in the updated post. Would you be able to provide any further guidance?

Comment: I went ahead and added the manifest to the original post. nothing out of the ordinary as far as I know

Comment: I think that the root cause is that your foo.jar actually doesn't embed foo.libs.jar - there is no Bundle-ClassPath referencing to the latter in its manifest, only Class-Path, which has no sense in OSGi. But generally, I'd advise you to reconsider your approach and minimize using Bundle-ClassPath. Usually, it's last resort in OSGi to embed bundles in each other, and it is used only for those dependencies, which are not OSGi bundles. In your case, I think it is possible to outline foo.jar to a separate bundle.

Comment: The ClassPath value gets autogenerated by Eclipse when it creates the manifest.  I have played around with removing the foo.libs.jar and adding all those jars directly to the project containing foo.jar.  I think that seems to work for now.

Comment: FYI you are correct that changing the Class-Path to Build-ClassPath also resolves the issue